# Can someone let me in on the 6-8 weeks joke?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Many Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta)

I have seen this joke so many times, but I guess I started reading Jeff's blog too late to get it. Where did the  6-8 weeks joke start?

Comment: I'll tell you later.  Ask me again in six to ei-- no, I can't do it.  It's too lame, even for me.

Comment: Have you ever filled out a mail-in rebate form? been told some form will take 6-8 weeks for "processing"?

Comment: See also: http://sixtoeightweeks.com/